# How to write reuseable components for pygame

Tags: python, component-based, pygame

Is there a recommended way to write reuseable components for pygame? Simple example would be a FPS counter. Should I write a class which has an init, update and draw method and call them from inside a game loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be pretty normal, pass the frame delta to update and pass in a destination surface to draw (which will normally be the screen).

Comment: sounds pretty good. does it makes sense to separate the update and draw logic like it's done in other game frameworks?

Comment: Yes, you might also want to divide update into physics step and game parameter updates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a recommended way, as such, for writing components but I often reuse buttons and other stuff for the game and pause menu which are initialized with Surfaces for mouse-states (hover, mouse-down, etc) and a function for click-events.

And of course, I have a vector class that I reuse all the time.

You definitely don't really need a module for basic timing and fps calculation though. Pygame's Clock-class is ideal for that. You just create a clock-object, call tick() once per frame and it returns the delta-time and keeps track of fps for you:

```
def main_loop():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()     
    counter = 0

    while game_is_running:          
        handle_events()

        lapse = clock.tick()        
        update_physics_and_stuff(lapse * BASE_SPEED_FACTOR)
        render()

        # once every second, display the fps
        counter += lapse           
        if counter > 1000:
            pygame.display.set_caption('fps: %1.2f' % clock.get_fps())
            counter = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The fps counter was just an example. What I wanted to know is how you structure your components so that you can reuse them easily in several other projects.